# Python File Hex operations

Tags: python

I am trying to read a hex value like this from a file and do some operations.

```
REVA: XA0 DID0, DF= Q8B8, Rev: 0.0, UT: 0xd2d32103800600 : Cbos: 18 (0x0)
```

I am trying to read UT and do the following operations on it.

```
x=ut  & 0xFFFFFFFF
y=(ut>>32) & 0xFFFFFF
```

My code is below-

```
f=open('utinfo', 'rb')

for line in f:
    if line.startswith("REVA"):
        ut=line.split()[8] #grabs the value 0xd2d32103800600 
    x   = ut & 0xFFFFFFFF
    y   = (ut>>32) & 0xFFFFFF
```

The error I get it is-

```
     x  = ut & 0xFFFFFFFF
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'long'
```

So I am reading the value as a string but I thought reading a file as rb would not cause this problem yet it is reading the value as a string.

Btw, this works in python

```
>>?ut=0x2d32103800600
>>? x=ut & 0xFFFFFFFF
>>?x
0x3800600L
>>? y= ut>>32 & 0xFFFFFF
>>?y
>>?0x0L
```

How do I fix this? Thanks a lot for your time & help.

Comment: you can cast the string to long `long(float(ut))` and then perform the bitwise operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Added base 16 to long conversion!

You're performing the `&` operation on different data types. Before doing that you have to convert the read `string` to `long` data type like this:

```
# at this moment ut data type is string
ut=line.split()[8] #grabs the value 0xd2d32103800600
# convert string to long data type, set base 16
ut = long(ut, 16)
```

And after that you may continue execute your code:

```
x   = ut & 0xFFFFFFFF
y   = (ut>>32) & 0xFFFFFF
```

## Full code:

```
f=open('utinfo', 'rb')
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("REVA"):
        ut=line.split()[8] #grabs the value 0xd2d32103800600 
        ut=long(ut,16)
    x   = ut & 0xFFFFFFFF
    y   = (ut>>32) & 0xFFFFFF
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: shouldn't we set base explicitly ```ut = long(ut, 16)```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support! Indeed it was necessary, I completely forgot about that. Fixed the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes I noticed. Thanks for the support :)